# sh 1 syntax error ( unexpected when trying to run external python script

Tags: python, shell

so when the program that is trying to run the code attempts to run the python script, it's running it in shell. I made sure it had a shebang so it ran with the proper interpreter but it keeps coming up with

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

despite it clearly being set to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and here is the code that is having problems

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Four arguments, password host channel and message.
# EG: "ircbot_message.py hunter2 example.com #adminchannel ADMINHELP"
import sys
import socket

def pack():

    try:
        data = sys.argv[4:]
        print(data)
    except:
        data = "NO DATA SPECIFIED"
    data = str(data)
    data = bytes(data, "ascii")
    nudge(data)

def nudge(data):
    HOST = sys.argv[2]
    PORT = 45678
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.send(data)
    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__" and len(sys.argv) > 1:  # If not imported and more than one argument
    pack()
```

I am running ubuntu 18.04 server edition on a cloud server up on a dedicated box in canada.
Oh and it's python 3.6.8.

adding more information. the snippet that sends the command to the py script

```
/proc/ext_python(var/script, var/args, var/scriptsprefix = 1)
    if(scriptsprefix) script = "scripts/" + script

    if(world.system_type == MS_WINDOWS)
        script = replacetext(script, "/", "\\")

    var/command = config.python_path + " " + script + " " + args
    shell("[command]")
    return
```

and to call it

```
usr/bin/python3 ircbot_message.py commskey "iphere" null "ADMIN - HELP ME IM DYING INSIDE"
```

and in DM

```
/proc/send2irc(var/msg, var/admin = 0)
    if(config.use_irc_bot)
        paranoid_sanitize(msg)
        if(admin)
            msg = "ADMIN - [msg]"
        // 3rd param is unused in the bot, would spend time to fix this but I'm lazy. - Jon
        ext_python("ircbot_message.py", "[config.comms_password] [config.irc_bot_host] null [msg]")
    return
```

Comment: What is your parameters when you call the script ?

Comment: the code is in dm so it calls as such
`/proc/ext_python(var/script, var/args, var/scriptsprefix = 1)
 if(scriptsprefix) script = "scripts/" + script

 if(world.system_type == MS_WINDOWS)
  script = replacetext(script, "/", "\\")

 var/command = config.python_path + " " + script + " " + args
 shell("[command]")
 return`
where `shell("[command]")` will send it to the shell... in the name

Comment: Can you show us how you call this script? I mean the actual shell script. Edit: Please put above snippet inside your question to make it more readable.

Comment: `shell()`, like all other `system()` equivalents, is a Generally Bad Idea and should not be used. Beyond that, though -- is the execute bit set on the file's permissions? (If not, it can't be executed via the `execve()` syscall, so the shebang isn't honored by the kernel and you're relying on the calling process to do the right thing -- which it frequently won't).

Comment: BTW, what *is* this "DM"? Python expertise is only helpful if the Python interpreter is actually being started, which it isn't here; if DM is the programming language that's supposed to be invoking that interpreter, you have a problem with (and should be asking about) DM, not Python; someone who knows it could hopefully point you to an OS interface that lets you provide an explicit argv instead of a shell command line when running an external process

Comment: DM is a coding language referred as to DreamMaker which is only slightly similar to Python to a degree, the language is owned by BYOND (Build your own net dream) a niche games making platform. I do agree that DM might be the cause as `shell("[command]"` is the **only way to pass a command to the shell** in the current codebase. there is an RCE patch already baked into the Python.dm